# ColdFusion Query of Queries 100 x Slower than the Database Call Itself (with relatively low record counts)

Tags: performance, coldfusion, report

We have an analytics chart which first queries the database log table to pull all relevant from an optimized query only selecting what is needed along with grabbing relevant start and end ID's since this table has millions of records.  Once that initial query is pulled, we have used ColdFusion's query of queries to work with that data to display different charts.

You can see the actual external database call in this example grabs 2,240 records in 31ms:

```
qryGetLogs (Datasource=ourDSN, Time=31ms, Records=2204)
```

We have a chart that displays views per hour for each day of the week and then builds a jQuery chart to display them.  From the initial design, those queries execution times were almost negligible, most often at 0ms. Because we loop over each hour in the day (24) for 7 days a week, that is 168 queries - one of the main reasons to not make the external DB call so many times.

It seems now that many, but not all, of those query of queries are taking over 100 times longer to run than the initial database call.  Most of them are using the BETWEEN date range function to select the records for each day and hour part:

```
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=4312ms, Records=5)
SELECT createdOn, DayOfWeek
FROM qryGetLogs
WHERE  (CreatedOn BETWEEN '2012-09-03 0:00:00' AND '2012-09-03 0:59:59')
AND (DayOfWeek = 2)
```

You can see that query of another query took 4,312ms and was searching through a query with 2,240 records.  Here are the query times for many of the next queries:

```
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=4610ms, Records=5)
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=4187ms, Records=8)
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=5062ms, Records=6)
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=3985ms, Records=0)
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=4828ms, Records=2)
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=5750ms, Records=0)
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=3016ms, Records=4)
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=3625ms, Records=6)
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=6265ms, Records=11)
```

So you can see just by those queries about, it added 40 seconds of loading time!  But notice the next query is just 78ms with more records than any of the previous query, and many after that, the times are better:

```
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=78ms, Records=18)
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=62ms, Records=7)
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=63ms, Records=12)
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=78ms, Records=34)
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=78ms, Records=9)
```

Those go on for a while with good times, then BAM! Back to the 2-6 second queries.

```
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=4891ms, Records=13)
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=1984ms, Records=8)
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=4875ms, Records=4)
qryViewsPerHour (Datasource=, Time=6203ms, Records=0)
```

All in all, what was taking several seconds to load, is taking between 100-400 seconds loads, and that is just the weekly report!  We also use it for monthly reports.

I have monitored the server and made sure that I am the only person or process running the request, so it should not be that the CPU's resources are being eaten up by something else, and I also monitor the CPU request and it's solid and steady being used by JRUN.exe.

Does anyone have any advice on this problem?  It is driving me nuts!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you really need to loop? Ideally you should build the resultset in a *db query* because full fledged databases are generally much more efficient at querying than QoQ's. Without knowing more, it certainly sounds like this could be done in a single query.

Comment: Agreed - one could even simply retrieve the data from the DB, loop over the data set, and populate a structure (would be a struct of structs). Using QoQ here seems inappropriate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically, query of queries are wonderfully fast.  However, there are times it may take longer when volumes increase.  Since you are well within the recommended 5,000 to 50,000 row recommendation by ColdFusion documentation, it can only be one thing.  Some where some data is being translated to get the results.  In this case, it's the date time that you've specified.   The time value has one leading zero.  I know it sounds strange.

**CHANGE:**
    WHERE  (CreatedOn BETWEEN '2012-09-03 0:00:00' AND '2012-09-03 0:59:59')

**TO:**
    WHERE  (CreatedOn BETWEEN '2012-09-03 00:00:00' AND '2012-09-03 00:59:59')

I tested this and found the results were better.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This seems to have solved the performance issues.  We were looping through 1 to 24, and the hour parts with 1 digit didn't have a leading 0, and adding that leading 0 in seems to have made all of the difference in the world.

Comment: @ArMan - Wow, if that is true, it is a great example of why you should always use date *objects* in queries, and **not** strings. While a real database would do a much better job optimizing the execution of that statement, implicit conversion is still "...like a box of chocolates. You never know what you're going to get" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Although Coldfusion has the functionaility of performing a query of queries in my experience it is a last resort. Reason being how inefficient and limited it is. CF is a programming language, not a SQL language and as such its doesn't not have any of the optimization features a real DB would have.

I would strongly reccomend pushing the queries onto the database instead and if you have a DB that supports views I would also recommend creating a view based on your original query so you only need to perform the subqueries on the view not the whole original tables.

Avoid Query of queries where possible, especially when working with large datasets because it has to all be stored in memory as hefty Java objects. and as Russ pointed out, is subject to the garbage collectors influence and as your reports grow could lead to out of memory problems. (I once knocked over my PC with an oversized QoQ)

Comment: Boy, I have to heartily disagree.  Q of Q can be a great tool to increase performance.  Given a properly configured CF server, I have rarely, if ever, GAINED performance by pushing Q of Q code to the DB, and would like to see some examples where this is the case.

Comment: I have only ever used QoQ when I've had to work around Poorly optimized, or insufficient databases. A properly configure DB will Always perform better (on a query by query basis) than CF because its what it's build to do.  I digress however, I've only been on CFML for a year and a half and have much to learn about the finer details or optimization.

Comment: I tend to agree with Dpolehonski. Databases are far superior at querying, hands down. However, they also incur additional overhead due to network traffic. In memory queries do not, but they require more of CF's memory resources than a typical database query. So it is a balance. QoQ's do have a place, but IMO they often overused or misused. Frequently, a well crafted database query would perform signifigantly better.

Comment: .. Under normal circumstances, your average database could calculate these kind of hourly/weekly/yearly totals in a single query. With proper indexes, it would be significantly faster and more efficient than the equivalent loop code - even with QoQ's. Looping always slows things down. So whenever possible, heavy data lifting should be done in the database, because it is specifically optimized for that job. Granted sometimes it is not possible due to other restrictions. That might be the case here. However, looping and QoQ's should not be the "first" choice.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you're seeing the JVM garbage collector at work. One option would be to try running a JVM monitoring tool in order to help tune your JVM for your specific needs. Another option would be to run the sub-queries on the database instead of with query of queries.

Comment: Hey there, we do have FusionReactor running on the server, it seems, so far, to have been the date formatting and not having a leading 0.

Comment: Instead of strings, use date objects. Then formatting is never an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you posted because I have just been assuming it would be better than doing the round trip back to the server.

But what about using:

```
cachedWithin="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,1,0)#"
```

That might be just as good as a Query of Queries.